# Grails find results in null List for hasMany relationship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have created an object (which is nested within a nested object) with a hasMany relationship and when I save the object, the items are saved, the list is fully populated.  But when I use find to get the object back from the database, the list is null

```
class Parent {

int age
String name
List<Child> children

static hasMany = [
  children: Child
]

}
```

So when I use Parent.findAll(), I get

```
{
  age: 34
  name: 'John Smith'
  children: null
}
```

What's weird is other classes I have don't display this behavior.  I set lazy to false for the list, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  What gives?

EDIT: Here is the child class

```
class Child {

    static constraints = {
        firstName nullable: true
        middleName nullable: true
        displayName nullable: true
        story nullable: true
    }

    static belongsTo = [
        parent: Parent,
        teacher: Teacher
    ]

  String firstName
  String middleName
  String displayName
  String story
}
```

Comment: show your Child class

Comment: @injecteer I've added it above

Comment: how do you know, that Parent.children items are saved? can you see the in the DB? Show also the relevant part of your saving method. What DB is in use?

Comment: I have checked it in the database (currently H2 for development purposes), and it is in there.  I’m using Parent.save(flush: true)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  Lazy loading is to blame.  All I had to do was add

```
children lazy: false
```

to the constraints on the parent class and the problem was solved!